# How to convert an alias for bash to an alias for csh? -> Or to tcl

Tags: bash, alias, tcl

`alias s2st="ps -A | grep -E "a|b""` works for bash.

Then I tried to convert it for `csh`:

```
set-alias t2st 'ps -A \| grep -E "a\|b"'
```

But csh does quoting so different, I couldn't coupe with...

How does it need to be, to be correct and working?

Answer (score 3):

In `bash`, that should be:

```
alias s2st='ps -A | grep -E "a|b"'
```

(`alias s2st="ps -A | grep -E "a|b""` would **not** work in `bash`, as the second `"` would close the first `"` so the second `|` would not be quoted).

In `csh`

```
alias s2st 'ps -A | grep -E "a|b"'
```

Strong quotes in both `bash` and `csh` are `'...'`. They are less strong in `csh` though where `!` and newline (and backslash when preceding those) are still special.

In TCL, strong quotes are `{...}` with the added benefit that `{` and `}` can occur within them as long as they  are matched.

Comment: Thanks! Ok, then my problem isn't csh, but tcl, which I expected to use the same syntax. How should it look like for tcl?

Comment: @jwk Your question does not mention tcl. Could you maybe update the question?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Stéphane Chazelas, I found my problem:

My alias is stored in a tcl script, so I need the correct tcl syntax, which is:

```
set-alias s2st {ps -A | grep -E "a|b"}
```

Comment: For clarity, the question and answer would benefit from showing a bit more context around how you use the shell and tcl. At the moment, the tcl bit seems to be quite important even though it's barely mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In Tcl I'd write

```
proc psgrep {pattern} {
    return [join [lsearch -regexp -inline -all [split [exec ps -A] \n] $pattern] \n]
}

set output [psgrep {a|b}]
```

Comment: But I don't think this is really what you're asking.